# ARX model selection

Tags: time-series, model-selection, aic, autoregressive

I have an autoregressive model with exogenous variables:

$S_{t} = \sum_{i=1}^{p} a_i S_{t-i} + \sum_q \sum_{i=1}^{r} b^q_i X^{q}_{t-i}$

where $S_t$ is the signal I want to predict and $X^q_t$ the qth external variable at lag $t$.

I have three years of data ($S$ and $X$) and now I'm trying to predict the signal $S$ for the fourth year. For that I have in real time the $X^q_t$ time series but no $S_t$. So I have fitted the best $ARX(p,r)$ for the first three years, and use this lag configuration to predict the fourth year, where for it I assume that the first $p$ signal lags are zero, i.e., $S_1,S_2,...,S_p =0$.

So, my question is: which criteria should I use to choose the best $(p,r)$ configuration?

I tried to calculate AICc using:

$AICc = NObs*ln(RSS/NObs)+2K+\frac{2K(2K+1)}{(NObs-K-1)}$

where $NObs$ is the total number of points I have for the first three years, $K$ the total number of parameters from $ARX(p,r)$ model and $RSS$ the residual sum of squares for the first three years.

The problem is that the lowest resulted AICs values (which in fact are negative) are for a $(p,r)$ configuration that is clearly overfitting the problem.

EDIT: The time granularity is weekly and it is "clearly overfitting" because the $RSS$ for the training set (first three years) is of order $10^{-7}$, i.e., there is a perfect fit, but the prediction is very bad. $NObs=27+37+37=101$

Comment: Hi, and welcome to CrossValidated! Could you please [edit your question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/146664/edit) to indicate what time granularity you have (daily? monthly? hourly?) and how you know that your $AIC_c$-selected orders are "clearly overfitting"?

Comment: Hello. Ok, corrected.

Comment: How large is $q$ and $r$? And why your years have 27 and 37 weeks instead of 52? I suspect that due to high $q$ and $r$ you have very large number of variables, hence the overfitting.

Comment: One example is: $(q,r) = (1,5)$, which means 96 parameters! The issue here is that I'm trying to find a criteria to choose a good $(q,r)$. I already found a good configuration $(q,r) = (10,2)$  that seems good. But this is only "thumb rule"...

Comment: Ah, and they do not have 52 weeks because my region of interest is localized. Outside these weeks the signal function is just zero.

Comment: How do you deal with the long strings of zeros in your data? ARX will try to fit lots of consecutive zeros, which does not make sense. If you just throw the zeros out, ARX will believe that an observation three months back is just one week old, which likely is also not what you want. I suspect your first problem is "fitting an ARX model with missing values".

Comment: Sorry, I made confusion. "Outside these weeks the signal function is just zero." is not true. The signal outside these weeks is fixed at a constant. So I don't have long string of zeros. But if it was zero outside the region of interest there is no problem. I start my time series in the region of interest only. So, for example, I'm just interest in the period of August to February. My time series (non zero) start in the first week of August and if the lag is, e.g, $(4,4)$, then the regression calculation starts at September.

Comment: Check how AIC changes with the number of parameters. Usually you pick the model in the knee of the curve to avoid overfitting.